# User-input value validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to show a warning when a parent button is clicked but it isn't working correctly. The warning is shown if the value of the input in any day in the past.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="well">
  <button class="expando" />
  <fieldset class="hire_date_wrapper">
    <label>Hire Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="input_name" /><br />
    <span class="date_warning">Warning message</span>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here is the js:

```
$('.expando').click(function(){
    var well = $(this).parents('.well');
    var hiredate = well.children('[name="input_name"]').val();
    var today = new Date();
    if (hiredate < today) {
        well.children('.date_warning').show();
    } else {
        well.children('.date_warning').hide();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert your typed date into a date object

```
$('.expando').click(function(){
    var well = $(this).parents('.well');
    var hiredate = new Date($( '[name="input_name"]', well).val());
    var today = new Date();
    if ( isNaN( hiredate.getTime() ) ) {
        $( '.date_warning', well ).show();
    } else {
        if (hiredate.getTime() < today.getTime()) {
            $( '.date_warning', well ).show();
        } else {
            $( '.date_warning', well ).hide();
        }
    }
});​
```

try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/TM5EK/

Comment: You'll get an error from redeclaring the variables with the `var` keyword if you try to run this one.

Comment: used the updated code and the error went away but its still not working for me.

Comment: ok, i updated my answer... there were many bugs with the selectors... it worked fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/TM5EK/

Comment: Yeah looks like it was a selector error, I figured it out just before I checked out your answer. Thanks so much for your help I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are just comparing the value of the input and a date object as opposed to 2 date objects.

Try making the hiredate into an object with `new Date(hiredate)`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UjVRY/

Code from the fiddle

```
var now = new Date(),
    hiredate = '2012-10-10',
    hiredateobj = new Date(hiredate);

$('#results_noobj').html((hiredate < now ? 'before' : 'after')+' now');
// Output 'after now'

$('#results_obj').html((hiredateobj < now ? 'before' : 'after')+' now');
// OUtputs 'before now'
```

​

Comment: Not sure I follow. Have an example?